# How can I find all the doors getting null exception?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first script that control the whole doors:
In this script I'm calling:

```
LockDoor(i);
```

Just for testing locking all the doors.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<HoriDoorManager> _doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    private void Start()
    {
        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        foreach(var door in doors)
        {
            _doors.Add(door.GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < _doors.Count; i++)
        {
            LockDoor(i);
        }

        // find all your doors and add them to the _doors collection
        // alternatively expose the collection to the UI and build it there
    }

    public void LockDoor(int doorIndex)
    {
        _doors[doorIndex].ChangeLockState(true);
    }
    public void UnlockDoor(int doorIndex)
    {
        _doors[doorIndex].ChangeLockState(false);
    }
}
```

The second script that attached to each door. And each door is built with two children doors that open by sliding to the sides:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool doorLockState;
    private List<DoorHori> doors = new List<DoorHori>();

    private void Start()
    {
        GameObject doorsParent = GameObject.Find("Wall_Door_Long_01");
        foreach(Transform door in doorsParent.transform)
        {
            doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
        } 
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (doors != null)
            {
               for(int i =0; i < doors.Count; i++)
                {
                    doors[i].OpenDoor();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ChangeLockState(bool lockState)
    {
        doorLockState = lockState;
    }
}
```

In the Start when it's adding the doors to the List all the doors are null:

```
GameObject doorsParent = GameObject.Find("Wall_Door_Long_01");
            foreach(Transform door in doorsParent.transform)
            {
                doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
            }
```

A screenshot of a door structure and the doors I'm trying to get in the HoriDoorManager script are the Door_Left and Door_Right

[image: Door structure]

Why it's null ? Should I make instance new instance for the List of doors on OnTriggerExit ? Comparing: `doorLockState = lockState;` is logic ?

When running the game all the doors are locked but I'm getting the null exception.

I solved the first problem:

Since the script is attached to a child first I'm checking if the child have a parent. Then getting the parent then searching for the specific "Wall_Door_Long_01" GameObject on this parent and then making a foreach over the "Wall_Door_Long_01" GameObject:

```
private void Start()
    {
        if(transform.parent != null)
        {
            Transform parent = transform.parent;
            var doorsParent = parent.Find("Wall_Door_Long_01");
            foreach(Transform door in doorsParent)
            {
                test.Add(door);
                doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is that the List test contains two GameObjects Door_Left and Door_Right and the List doors contains the two scripts from each of the doors.

Now I don't need the test List but I do need the doors List to be able to call the OpenDoor method.

Comment: Try using [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) to get components in children.

Comment: Which line is giving you null exception (could you please show full error)? Also can you take a picture of one of your doors in the inspector?

Comment: Ok I found my mistake. Updated my question.

Comment: Ok And the second main problem was that I forgot to attach the first script the DoorsManager to a empty GameObject. After doing that everything is working great. I can lock/unlock all the doors or lock/unlock specific doors.

Comment: Can you edit or re-ask this question? The title says "null" but the question seems to be about getting access to specific methods on the objects. I'd recommend a new question -- that's the [preferred pattern on Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290746/173225)